# Spring-MVC, InheritanceType.JOINED, and automatic mapping of JSON objects to entities with Jackson

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, jackson

We're trying to write an API that creates *elements* of different types. The elements have a JPA entity representation. The following code shows how our basic element structure looks like (simplified):

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Element {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String type;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Every element implementation looks different but this example should be enough:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class SpecializedElement1 extends Element {

    @Column
    private String attribute;

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

}
```

We use Jackson and a typical controller action looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createElement", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, Object> create(@RequestBody Element element) {
    HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>()
    response.put("element", element);
    response.put("status", "success");
    return response;
}
```

A typical request body looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "constantStringForSpecializedElement1"
    "text": "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet cow bacon drumstick shankle ham hock hamburger."
}
```

As you will see: This does not work since Jackson does not know how to map this object to SpecializedElement1.

The question is: How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. That's the solution:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonTypeInfo(
    // We use the name defined in @JsonSubTypes.Type to map a type to its implementation.
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    // The information that stores the mapping information is a property.
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    // The property is called "type".
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpecializedElement1.class, name = "specializedElement1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpecializedElement1.class, name = "specializedElement2")
})
public class Element {
    // ....
}
```

This controller action works as expected...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> create(@RequestBody Element element) {
    if (element == null) {
        // Return an error response.
    }
    try {
        return elementService.update(element);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Return an error response.
    }
}
```

... with this request:

```
POST /create/
... more headers ...
Content-Type: application/json


{
    "type": "specializedElement1"
}
```